# NetSuite Restlet Error Handling and Re-Try in code fail

Tags: netsuite

I have a question on Restlet. How should we handle possible errors? For instance, an external application calls the Restlet to update some data but for some reason the Restlet fails. I have a catch shown below:

```
catch (err)
{
    var errMessage = err;
    if(err instanceof nlobjError)
    {
        errMessage = errMessage + ' ' + err.getDetails() + ' ' + errMessage;
    }
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Error', errMessage)
}
```

Is that sufficient to send back to the caller?

What about when the Restlet tries updating or retrieving data from external app and fails...is there a way the restlet can 're-try' running itself or is this only possible in a scheduled script?

Answer (score 4):

Personally I prefer to `throw` errors out of my Restlets. When you `throw` an error, NetSuite will return a `400 - Bad Request` response code. If you let the Restlet `return` normally, whether you found an error or not, NetSuite will return a `200 - OK` response code. Most clients detect error/success with the response code, not by inspecting the response data.